# how to mock a named import in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I used to have a set up like so:

```
export class MyClass {
}
export default new MyClass()
```

then I would do: `import myclass from 'libraries/myclass'`

now I change it to:

`export const myclass = new MyClass()`

and importing like so `import { myclass } from 'libraries/myclass'` which seems to work in my code

however all my jest tests are failing

I'm currently doing:

```
jest.mock('libraries/myclass', () => ({
    myclassfunction: jest.fn(),
}))
```

I've tried changing to:

```
jest.mock('./myclass.js', () => (
  {
    ...(jest.requireActual('./myclass.js')),
    myclassfunc: () => {}
  }
))
```

but it still fails and when I `console.log(myclass)` it is coming through as undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can use jest automock featurein your test, do you need to use the factory to mock it?

```
import { myclass } from 'libraries/myclass';
jest.mock('libraries/myclass'); 

// myclass is now a mock
```

Comment: you are providing a factory, if you change it to be auto mock then `myclass` should be mocked